Getting an error While uploading image folder on pinata using pinFromFS function in nodejs
I am uploading approx 2.3 GBi of folder to pinata using pinFromFS() now i am getting error given below:
Error: write EPROTO
    at afterWriteDispatched (node:internal/stream_base_commons:160:15)
    at writevGeneric (node:internal/stream_base_commons:143:3)
    at Socket._writeGeneric (node:net:950:11)
    at Socket._writev (node:net:959:8)
    at doWrite (node:internal/streams/writable:588:12)
    at clearBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:766:5)
    at onwrite (node:internal/streams/writable:644:7)
    at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (node:internal/stream_base_commons:106:10) {
  errno: -100,
  code: 'EPROTO',
  syscall: 'write',
  config: {
    url: 'https://api.pinata.cloud/pinning/pinFileToIPFS',
    method: 'post',
    data: FormData {
      _overheadLength: 1588894,
      _valueLength: 0,
      _valuesToMeasure: [Array],
      writable: false,
      readable: true,
      dataSize: 0,
      maxDataSize: 2097152,
      pauseStreams: true,
      _released: true,
      _streams: [],
      _currentStream: null,
      _insideLoop: false,
      _pendingNext: false,
      _boundary: '--------------------------174342881892821561124369',
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 1
    },
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary= --------------------------174342881892821561124369',
      pinata_api_key: 'my_pinata_api_key',
      pinata_secret_api_key: 'my_pinata_secret_key',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.21.1'
    },
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    withCredentials: true,
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: Infinity,
    maxBodyLength: Infinity,
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus]
  },
  request: <ref *1> Writable {
    _events: {
      close: undefined,
      error: [Function: handleRequestError],
      prefinish: undefined,
      finish: undefined,
      drain: undefined,
      response: [Function: handleResponse]
    },
    _writableState: WritableState {
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      length: 0,
      corked: 0,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writelen: 0,
      bufferedIndex: 0,
      pendingcb: 0,
      [Symbol(kState)]: 17580812,
      [Symbol(kBufferedValue)]: null
    },
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _options: {
      maxRedirects: 21,
      maxBodyLength: Infinity,
      protocol: 'https:',
      path: '/pinning/pinFileToIPFS',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: [Object],
      agent: undefined,
      agents: [Object],
      auth: undefined,
      hostname: 'api.pinata.cloud',
      port: null,
      nativeProtocols: [Object],
      pathname: '/pinning/pinFileToIPFS'
    },
    _ended: true,
    _ending: true,
    _redirectCount: 0,
    _redirects: [],
    _requestBodyLength: 2574078661,
    _requestBodyBuffers: [
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      ... 64178 more items
    ],
    _eventsCount: 2,
    _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
    _currentRequest: ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: true,
      _last: false,
      chunkedEncoding: true,
      shouldKeepAlive: true,
      maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      strictContentLength: false,
      _contentLength: null,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      _closed: true,
      _header: 'POST /pinning/pinFileToIPFS HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary= --------------------------174342881892821561124369\r\n' +
        'pinata_api_key:my_pinata_api_key\r\n' +
        'pinata_secret_api_key:my_pinata_secret_key\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios/0.21.1\r\n' +
        'Host: api.pinata.cloud\r\n' +
        'Connection: keep-alive\r\n' +
        'Transfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'POST',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
      path: '/pinning/pinFileToIPFS',
      _ended: false,
      res: null,
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: [Function: emitRequestTimeout],
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'api.pinata.cloud',
      protocol: 'https:',
      _redirectable: [Circular *1],
      [Symbol(shapeMode)]: false,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: true,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kChunkedBuffer)]: [],
      [Symbol(kChunkedLength)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kSocket)]: [TLSSocket],
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype],
      [Symbol(errored)]: null,
      [Symbol(kHighWaterMark)]: 16384,
      [Symbol(kRejectNonStandardBodyWrites)]: false,
      [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
    },
    _currentUrl: 'https://api.pinata.cloud/pinning/pinFileToIPFS',
    [Symbol(shapeMode)]: true,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  response: undefined,
  isAxiosError: true,
  toJSON: [Function: toJSON]
}



Solution:
Start with increasing the timeout and using the Pinata SDK. If issues persist, check network conditions and ensure your Node.js version is up-to-date.
1. Increase Timeout:
Ensure your Axios timeout is long enough for large uploads:
const pinataSDK = require('@pinata/sdk');
const pinata = pinataSDK('your_pinata_api_key', 'your_pinata_secret_api_key');

async function uploadFolder(folderPath) {
    try {
        const config = {
            timeout: 500000 // Adjust as needed
        };
        const result = await pinata.pinFromFS(folderPath, config);
        console.log('Folder pinned:', result);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error pinning folder:', error);
    }
}

uploadFolder('/path/to/your/large/folder');

2. Use Pinata SDK:
Use the Pinata SDK to handle large files more effectively:
const pinataSDK = require('@pinata/sdk');
const pinata = pinataSDK('your_pinata_api_key', 'your_pinata_secret_api_key');

async function uploadFolder(folderPath) {
    try {
        const result = await pinata.pinFromFS(folderPath);
        console.log('Folder pinned:', result);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error pinning folder:', error);
    }
}

uploadFolder('/path/to/your/large/folder');

3. Monitor Network Conditions
Check for:

Firewall settings
ISP limitations
Temporary downtimes from Pinata

